# Python - How to save a list as an image?

Tags: image, list, python-2.7, jpeg, python-imaging-library

I generate a regular list. Is it possible to save this list as a JPEG image or PNG or whatever so that I can open the image and look at it? I am currently trying to figure it out using the python imaging library (PIL).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one of the possible solutions:

1. Create an empty image object using: Image.new(mode, size, color)
2. Modify the image object to contain the data from the "list"
3. Save the image

E.g.:

```
new_img = Image.new("L", (NEW_X_SIZE, NEW_Y_SIZE), "white")
new_img.putdata(new_img_list)
new_img.save('out.tif')
```